# html5 video source not skipped in mobile browsers

Tags: html, html5-video, mobile-safari

I have a video element on a page that looks like the following

```html
<video>
  <source src="high-quality.webm"/>
  <source src="low-quality.webm"/>
</video>
```

I can not ensure that both `high-quality.webm` and `low-quality.webm` are available, so I rely on the browser to check both (starting with the first) and take the first that can be played. [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) says

> If the `type` attribute isn't specified, the media's type is retrieved from the server and checked to see if the browser can handle it; if it can't be rendered, the next `source` is checked

This works pretty well on all desktop browsers. But on mobile browsers, `low-quality.webm` is not played if `high-quality.webm` is not present.

Android Dev Tools report the following:

> **StagefrightMetadataRetriever** Unable to create data source for 'my.server.com/path/to/high-quality.webm'.
>
> **MediaResourceGetter** Invalid url: java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000

If I swap `high-quality.webm` and `low-quality.webm` (I can ensure that `low-quality.webm` is always available) no browser will look for `high-quality.webm` as he already found a playable source.

I want to avoid server-side checking which sources are available. The documentation sounded like browsers would do the job for me.

**tl;dr**

Can you tell me a way to play `high-quality.webm` if it is available, and `low-quality.webm` if not, on mobile browsers (as it works perfectly on the desktop)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by not available? You mean 404? Why would it only be available some of the time?

Comment: The video-element I described is part of a template we use for thousands of different videos with different folders, but named all after this scheme (a uuid like `abcdefgh` is converted to the folder `/ab/cd/ef/gh/`). Some resources are high-quality, so we name them `high-quality.webm` and create a `low-quality.webm` with ffmpeg. Som resources are not, so there we can not provide a high quality version, and the folder contains only a `low-quality.webm`. (in my eyes it would be better to name the videos unique, not their paths, but touching our whole folder structure is too expensive).

Answer (score 0):

With the new Version of Chrome Mobile there is no longer a problem.